# Is it possible to give standing permission to screen share in Microsoft Lync 2013?

Tags: permissions, lync

My company has been happily using Google Apps for almost a year now. However, we have a few remote computers that we periodically need to access - for that, we have been using the free version of TeamViewer - which only allows 5 minutes of use before kicking us out. Aside from violating the "we aren't using the commercially" agreement, it's very inconvenient. It was my hope that we could kill 2 birds with one stone by switching to Microsoft Lync. I am mostly happy so far, but here's my issue:

The remote computers we need access to often have no one in front of them, is it possible to allow standing permission for certain (or even all) users to screen share without input from a user on that end?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible:

> [Lync wrapper and WPF control](https://github.com/tomorgan/Lync-UISuppression-VideoAutoAnswer) to allow you to easily create UI Suppression mode applications which auto-answer incoming video calls

and also http://LyncAutoAnswer.com which uses the same code but might be solving a different problem I think.

Comment: I don't think this is really what I was looking for - I need a "request access" for screen sharing - not video calls. Or am I missing something?